# Loop Through Array Of Images To Generate Table React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to generate a soccer points table in React from an array of images. For instance this is my array:

```
import arsenal from './images/Arsenal.png';
import bournemouth from './images/AFCBournemouth.png';
import villa from './images/AstonVilla.png';

const icons =[{arsenal},{bournemouth},{villa}];
```

At the moment my class is created like this:

```
class Standings extends React.Component{

render(){

return(
<Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
  <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Teams</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src={bournemouth} class="icon" height="42" width="42" />
            </td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src={arsenal} class="icon" height="42" width="42" />
            </td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src={villa} class="icon" height="42" width="42" />
            </td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</Table>
)

}


}
```

Is there a way to generate the table by looping through the image array? I'd like to add more images to the array if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
const icons =[arsenal, bournemouth, villa];

class Standings extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Teams</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {icons.map((url, idx) => (
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src={url} class="icon" height="42" width="42" />
              </td>
              <td>{idx}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the map works but the image does not process in the table...

Comment: @clattenburgcake Use `const icons =[arsenal, bournemouth, villa];`

Comment: Apologies. Did not see that change!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects with the teams:

```
const teams = [
    {
       url: 'url',
       name: 'Arsenal,
       points: 3
    }
]
```

Then iterate over it:

```
<Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
 <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Teams</th>
            <th>Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
{
    teams.map((team) => (
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src={team.url} class="icon" height="42" width="42" />
            </td>
            <td>{ team.points }</td>
        </tr>
}
        </tbody>
</Table>
```

Also, if that does not work try to set the src of img like this:

```
<img src={{uri: team.url}} />
```